# SharePoint 2013 clients side refresh caml query of xsltlistviewwebpart

Tags: sharepoint, client-side, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 Server.
I need get content from document library based on CAML Query client side. Is any options to achieve this with out of box web parts?
I tried xsltlistviewwebpart with parameterbinding, but I can't change parameter after page loaded from javascript. Manual refresh of web part just refresh data with same query.

Maybe there is options to query SharePoint REST Service and bind result to some out of box web part? Or only option is render data manually?

Thank you!

Comment: What version of SharePoint 2013 ? Enterprise have a Content Search Web Part.

Comment: @PhilippeLavoie, thank you for answer. Enterprise. Can I set search query of CSWP client side dynamically via javascript?

Comment: The CSWQ will be configure to search for specific items. This search will occur on a client-side base. It's suppose to be async. Why do you need JS code ?

Comment: I want to implement client-side only solution (without server-side code). Depend on query param i need call external web service for data (url of folder in my case), then perform search or query for this data (i need show documents in this folder). I can do it with custom rendering, but I think that better uproach will be to use out-of-box web part. But all say that it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If your CAML query is short enough to be passed via QueryString then you can use QueryString parameter binding.

**Binding:**

```
<ParameterBinding Name="CAML" Location="QueryString(CAML)" DefaultValue="" />
```

**Query:**

```
<Query>{CAML}</Query>
```

As for refreshing XsltListViewWebPart following AJAX Options should be enabled:

```
Enable Asynchronous Update
Show Manual Refresh Button
```

**Sample CAML:**

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name="ID" />
         <Value Type="Number">1</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
```

So you can use link with encoded CAML like

```
/Lists/SampleList/CustomView.aspx?CAML=%3CWhere%3E%3CEq%3E%3CFieldRef%20Name%3D%22ID%22%20%2F%3E%3CValue%20Type%3D%22Number%22%3E1%3C%2FValue%3E%3C%2FEq%3E%3C%2FWhere%3E
```

If necessary you can trigger manual refresh button with JS

Also you maybe intrested in [alternative binding locations](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.ru/2010/09/xsltlistviewwebpart-contentbyquerywebpa.html)